# How to set up another simulation more conveniently?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is the scenario. I open a gzserver and then a gzclient. Now if I want to open another simulation, that is, another gzserver and I want to clear out the previous simulated robot. How should I do? I will shutdown gzserver and gzclient and open another gzserver and gzclient but it is not very convenient.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8145/how-to-set-up-another-simulation-more-conveniently?/) by [winston](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1084/winston/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 449 on 2015-03-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can start multiple `gzserver` instances on the same machine using the `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI` environment variable. Here is an example

1. Start `gzserver` and `gzclient`. By default they operate on `localhost:11345`

   Terminal 1: `gzserver`

   Terminal 2: `gzclient`
2. Start a `gzserver` and `gzclient` on a different port

   Terminal 3: `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=localhost:11346 gzserver`

   Terminal 4: `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=localhost:11346 gzclient`

Here is a shorter version:

Terminal 1: `gazebo`

Terminal 2: `GAZEBO_MASTER_URI=localhost:11346 gazebo`

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2015-03-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1